# Is there a way to tell if an object is a class or an object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way to tell if an object is a class or an instance of a class? Does this look correct:

```
if (object is Class) {
    return "[class " + getQualifiedClassName(value) + "]";
}
else if (object is Object) {
    return "[object " + getQualifiedClassName(value) + "]";
}
```

It seems like this may not catch all cases.

**UPDATE**
Here's my function I'm using:

```
    /**
     * Get string value of an object if value is not simple. For primitives the value is not changed. 
     * For class objects, "[class ClassName]" is returned. 
     * For objects, "[object ClassName]" is returned.
     * */
    public static function getStringValue(value:*):* {
        if (ObjectUtil.isSimple(value)) {
            return value;
        }
        else if (value is Class) {
            return "[class " + getQualifiedClassName(value) + "]";
        }

        return "[object " + getQualifiedClassName(value) + "]";
    }
```

Comment: What is your goal with that, why do you want to know that?

Comment: I want to set a value at runtime. Sometimes I need to create a class for when I set a skin and sometimes I need to set an object. But before I can do that I want to show the user the current value of the skinClass value. So I getStyle(style) and if value is class I write "class" or "object" or so on. Then let the user set the value to something new the same way, by string.

Comment: Under what circumstances would it be a class and under which would it be an object?

Comment: If I use `component.getStyle("skinClass")` then a Class is returned. If I use `component.skin` it is an object.

Comment: Why do you have to find out if it is an `object` or a `class` if you already know that based on what function you called?

Comment: To me, the body your current function looks good as-is for this sort of detection.

Comment: @null good question. I could keep track but in some cases the value of the property or style will be null. This may be more likely with a style. If the value is null I want a way to set it to an object or class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, I think that may be the easiest way is to use `String()` :

```
var o:MyClass = new MyClass();
var m:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

trace(String(MyClass));     // gives : [class MyClass]
trace(String(o));           // gives : [object MyClass]

trace(String(MovieClip));   // gives : [class MovieClip]
trace(String(m));           // gives : [object MovieClip]
```

And to be more sure, I think that you can use [`flash.utils.describeType()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()) :

```
trace(describeType(o));

// gives : 
//  <type name="MyClass" base="Object" isDynamic="false" isFinal="false" isStatic="false">
//      <extendsClass type="Object"/>
//  </type> 

trace(describeType(MyClass));

// gives : 
//  <type name="MyClass" base="Class" isDynamic="true" isFinal="true" isStatic="true">
//      <extendsClass type="Class"/>
//      <extendsClass type="Object"/>
//      <accessor name="prototype" access="readonly" type="*" declaredBy="Class"/>
//      <factory type="MyClass">
//          <extendsClass type="Object"/>
//      </factory>
//  </type>
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 2):

`if (object is Class)` will indeed test if the object is a class, but it is ALSO an Object, since Class is a subclass of Object.
So your second test is unnecessary, since anything that is not null is an Object.

Comment: I have no AS3 compiler at hand :( How about `if (3 is Object)`? Will this return true?

Comment: @Vesper I pasted my function I'm using. It checks for primitives "simple", then check if it is a Class and then the last check is for Object.